# Fetching List Item based on two list

Tags: list, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a requirement for which i have been stuck on for few days. I would kindly require some help on this.

So,I have 3 Lists naming List A, List B, List C. 
List A acts as a master list which has all the columns along with their data. 
List B has only the employee Names as people picker field.
List C is where i want to fetch the data and it acts as a destination.

Now, what i want is to Get the employee name From List B and match it With names in List A and then get Project names of employees based on the names that i have fetched in List C. 
I have tried getting the Data directly from List A into List C but i cannot fetch all the  employee names from List A into List C. 
Example : say there are 12 Employee Names in List A i am getting only 7 Names in List C.
That is why i am trying the three List Approach
Please Help if possible.
Below i am attaching my code used for fetching Names from List A into List C.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" 
  type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js" 
   type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
var employeeName=$("input[title^='Employee Name']").val();
$("input[title^='Employee Name']").hide();
$("input[title^='Employee Name']").after("<select id='EmployeeField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
$("input[title^='Project Name']").hide();
$("input[title^='Project Name']").after("<select id='ProjectField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
var allEmployeeNames=getAllEmployeeNames();
console.log(allEmployeeNames)
    $.each(allEmployeeNames,function(i,employee){
    $.each(employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.results,function(j,item){
        if(employeeName==item.Title){
            $("#EmployeeField").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");
        }else{
            if(item.Title!=undefined){
                $("#EmployeeField").append("<option value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");
            }           
        }   
    });         
});
$("#EmployeeField option").each(function() {
    $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
});
$("#EmployeeField").change(function(){
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").val($(this).val());
    var projects=getAllProjects($(this).val());
    $("#ProjectField").html("<option value=''></option>");
    $.each(projects,function(i,project){
        $("#ProjectField").append("<option value='"+project.Project_x0020_Name+"' pdate='"+project.End_x0020_Date+"'>"+project.Project_x0020_Name+"</option>");
    });
    $("#ProjectField option").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
    });
}); 
$("#ProjectField").change(function(){
    $("input[title^='Project Name']").val($(this).val());
    var pDate=$(this).find("option:selected").attr("pdate");    
    $("input[title^='End Date']").val(moment(pDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
});


})
          function getAllEmployeeNames(){
         var results;
        $.ajax({
       url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + 
 "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items $select=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id&$top=2000&$filter= Title eq null",
    type: "GET",
    async:false,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){
            results=data.d.results;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
    //alert("Error");
    }
});
return results;
    }
   function getAllProjects(employeeName){
var results;
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Project_x0020_Name,End_x0020_Date,Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$filter=Status eq 'Completed' and Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title eq '"+employeeName+"'&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id",
    type: "GET",
    async:false,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){
            results=data.d.results;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
    //alert("Error");
    }
});
return results;
  }
```

Comment: you messed all things together.

Comment: go step by step you can achieve it easily

Comment: could you help me regarding this?

Comment: yes i can is it sharepoint online?

Comment: yes it is sharepoint online

Comment: can you share the credentials...

Comment: i cannot give you access to the site. i am sorry

Comment: any other way you can help

Comment: you just need to check you select change function because value is not going properly that's the reason it is not populating properly.

Comment: so in the code if i get only top 100 items from the list i am not getting all the 14 names but 7 names but other functionality like fetching project based on names is also working but as i get more than 100 records it fetches duplicate value and the functionality stops working.

Comment: remove filter from rest and check what record is coming

Comment: all the list items are coming but few names are populating in drop down which also include duplicate values

Comment: if this is a case then. you should bind only unique valu in dropdown

Comment: any example for this

Answer (score 0):

Hey can you please tell your exact requirement clearly ?

If I do have a list name A, and i have 10 employee name in the employee cloum, 
then I do have a 2nd list named B , there I do have 7 employee name in the employee colum,
And you have third list name C , where you want to fetch the matching name , is this your requirement ?

Comment: Actually i want to fetch the employee name from List A to List B in a dropdown. As sharePoint allows to fetch 100 items at default, i used the Top function, but i do not get all the employee names in List B.